# Scholarship case - Accepting more than one university offer

Tags: funding, united-kingdom

I have applied for the said foundation as well as the Chevening Scholarship to pursue my Master's degree (Postgraduate).
Recently, I received two universities offers.
At the beginning and as a Syrian student, I did not know that accepting an offer may affect accepting other offers. So I accepted a university with an average ranking. 
Now that I have received an offer from a better university, can I accept other universities' offers? Knowing that I need to accept at least two universities offers, because the universities that I applied for in the first scholarship differ from the other one. And each university is giving me 4 weeks to accept the offer, if I did not accept the offer I will not be able to provide my offers to the scholarship committee after 4 month if they picked me. Many thanks. I would really appreciate a prompt answer for this dilemma.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't realize that saying to one university "yes, I accept to study full time at your university" meant that you couldn't accept the same thing at another university? Even as a student of another country, you should have understood this.
For the matter of needing to accept 2 different universities for 2 different scholarships: you can't. Either you need both scholarships to agree to both pay for the same university, or you need to make do with 1 scholarship.

Comment: sorry, I did not mean to be rude in my question. The only thing that I am afraid of being rejected from the scholarships in which I accepted its university offer. consequently, If I won the other one, I will loss it's universities' offers. Thank you for your courteous, timely response.

Comment: @samardati The answer to that question depends upon the specifics of the scholarships and is considered off-topic here.